# Monaca Vue 2 + onsenui Undefined method?

Tags: vuejs2, monaca, onsen-ui2

Created a project with monaca / vue2 / onsenui splitter template.
Defined a test method into the main.js file as follow :

```
import 'onsenui';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueOnsen from 'vue-onsenui';

// Onsen UI Styling and Icons
require('onsenui/css-components-src/src/onsen-css-components.css');
require('onsenui/css/onsenui.css');

import App from './App.vue';

Vue.use(VueOnsen);

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<app></app>',
  components:{App} , 
  methods: {

    test: function () {

      console.log('testing');


    }

    }
 });
```

then call to method is here on @click into homepage.vue

```
<template>
    <v-ons-page>
      <custom-toolbar :title="'Home'" :action="toggleMenu"></custom-toolbar>
      <p style="text-align: center">
        Welcome home.

         <button v-on:click="test">test</button>

      </p>
    </v-ons-page>
</template>

<script>


  import customToolbar from './toolbar'
  export default {
    props: ['toggleMenu'],
    components: { customToolbar } 
  }
</script>
```

Its always returning method as undefined, i am missing something...

Project structure :

[image: Project structure]

Comment: homepage.vue doesn't have a method called `test`

Comment: @thanksd i tried that way on homepage.vue

      export default {
  ................ , 
        methods : {test}
      }
doesn't help :(

Comment: Well, it'd need to look like `export default { ... , methods: { test: function() { } } }` right?

Comment: that did the trick, but if i want to use this method into another place in the app. I have to redeclare it in each vue ? sounds odd. or should i use vuex ?

Comment: Vuex is for state management. In this case, `test` is a click handler, or UI. You could trigger Vuex changes from inside your click handler, but it is unlikely you would want to re-use a click handler very often.

Comment: Thanks to you all. so i can't share a method app-wide ? should redeclare a method into each view that will use it, doesn't looklike a good pattern

Comment: @direxit You can use a Vue mixin to implement that method in any component you need.

Comment: @FranDios I will dig that Fran txs a lot !